# Mongo -- Bulk Find and update whole doc except for one field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am performing a bulk update/upsert operation on several thousand docs at a time from a csv. I update the whole document with a `$set` and that is currently working fine.

If the doc exists, I want to persist one field, which is only available from the db and I don't have input access to. So I have to fetch this field in the `.find()`, apply it to the doc in memory and then update the doc with a `$set` in the `update()` I can't seem to apply logic in between the `bulk.find()` and `.update()`

Here's a sample snippet:

```
// This is currently the code I'm implementing, works fine
users.forEach((user) => {
  bulk.find({ username: user.username})
  .updateOne({ $set: { user } });
});
bulk.execute();
```

What I would like to do would be something like this:

```
// code won't work, this is what I'm attempting to do
users.forEach((user) => {
  bulk.find({ username: user.username}, function (dbUser) {
    if (dbUser) user.email = dbUser.email;
  })
  .updateOne({ $set: { user } });
});
```

But bulk.find().update() doesn't allow intermediate logic as far as I can devise. Anyone have a work around or docs I can't seem to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution. Combine find/updateOne with `upsert()` and `$setOnInsert`.
So what's going on here is we look for a user in the database, if they exist, we just update a few fields with `$set`.
If the user is not in the db we insert them with the fields from `$set` as well as the rest of the user object via `$setOnInsert`. If a user already exists in the db, the `$set` is applied to them, but they skip over the `$setOnInsert` method.

The keys between the two methods need to be mutually exclusive for this to work.

```
 users.forEach((user) => {
        bulk
            .find(pick(user, 'email', 'username'))
            .upsert()
            .updateOne({
                $set: pick(user, keysToExcludeOnUpsert),
                $setOnInsert: omit(user, keysToExcludeOnUpsert)
            });
    });
```